# Why is $(X\times EG)/G\to X/G$ a fibration if $G$ acts freely on $X$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose that $G$ acts freely on $X$, and let $EG$ be a contractible space on which $G$ acts freely. According to many references, the projection $(X\times EG)/G\to X/G$ is a fibration.

However, I can't find a proof for this, nor construct one myself.

Comment: Hint: the fiber is $EG/G$.

Comment: The fiber is $EG$? Can I determine if a map is a fibration by looking at the fibers?

Comment: 1) The fiber is $EG/G$, not $EG$. 2) A more profound hint: $(X\times EG)/G=(X/G)\times (EG/G)$. 3) Just in case: do you know the definition of a fibration?

Comment: 1) I'm sorry, I forgot to say that I equipped $X\times EG$ with the diagonal $G$-action, i.e. the action given by $g.(x,e)= (gx,ge)$, so $(X\times EG)/G$ is not $X/G\times EG/G$. 3) According to Hatcher: A fibration is a map $p: E\to B$ having the homotopy lifting property w.r.t. all spaces $X$.